# Reading S3 path as data in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Our source provides data in the form: `s3://xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/mydate=2021-02-08/<lots of files>.parquet`. I need to read all the parquet files in the s3 folder `zzzz` and then add a column in the read data called `mydate` that corresponds to the date from which folder the parquet files belong to. Is this possible in Spark SQL?

Example:

Lets say I have these two paths to read data from:

`s3://xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/mydate=2021-02-08/abc.parquet`

`s3://xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/mydate=2021-02-09/pqr.parquet`

Data read from spark:

| Whatever columns | . | . | . | ... | mydate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| This row came from 2021-02-08 folder | . | . | . | ... | 2021-02-08 |
| This row came from 2021-02-09 folder | . | . | . | ... | 2021-02-09 |

Comment: For an input dataframe, you can use function `input_file_name()` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html) to get file names, and parse them to extract the date.

Comment: Exactly what was required. Thanks @mazaneicha

Answer (score 1):

You can read all the files under `s3://xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/mydate=2021-02-08/<lots of files>.parquet` into a `DataFrame` , then add the required `mydate` column

#### Data Preparation

```
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--packages=com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bundle:1.11.375,org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:3.2.0 pyspark-shell"


sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
sql = SQLContext(sc)

hadoop_conf = sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration()

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read(os.path.expanduser("~/.aws/credentials"))

access_key = config.get("****", "aws_access_key_id")
secret_key = config.get("****", "aws_secret_access_key")
session_key = config.get("****", "aws_session_token")


sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.endpoint", "s3.amazonaws.com")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.connection.ssl.enabled", "true")
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3a.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem");


hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3.aws.credentials.provider", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider")
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.access.key", access_key)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.secret.key", secret_key)
hadoop_conf.set("fs.s3a.session.token", session_key)

s3_path = "s3a://xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/mydate=2021-02-08"

sparkDF = sql.read.parquet(s3_path)
```

#### Extracting Date

```
>>> s3_path = "s3a://xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/mydate=2021-02-08"
>>> 
>>> 
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(s3_path)[0])
'mydate=2021-02-08'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(s3_path)[0]).split("=")[1]
'2021-02-08'
>>>
```

#### Adding Date Column

```
s3_path = "s3a://xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/mydate=2021-02-08"
mydate = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(s3_path)[0]).split("=")[1]

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('mydate',F.lit(mydate))
```

#### Adding Date Column - SparkSQL

```
s3_path = "s3a://xxxx/yyyy/zzzz/mydate=2021-02-08"
mydate = os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(s3_path)[0]).split("=")[1]

sparkDF.registerTempTable("TB1")

sql.sql(f"""
SELECT 
  *
  ,{mydate}
FROM TB1
""").show()
```